# Scrape data and write in single line for every iteration BS4 python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code. It all scraping the data. But my concern is to write the data in a single line for each iteration it goes.

Here is my code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib2
import re

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.codissia.com/member/members-directory/?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg=1")
content = page.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
eachbox = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile(r'members_box[12]')})
for eachuniversity in eachbox:
    data =  [re.sub('\s+', '', text).strip().encode('utf8') for text in eachuniversity.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
    print(','.join(data))
```

**UPDATE**

I want to the output to be like this (in single line) for an iteration

```
Name:,Mr.Srinivasan.N,Designation:,Proprietor,CODISSIA - Designation:,(Past President, CODISSIA),Name of the Industry:,Arian Soap Manufacturing Co,Specification:,LIFE,Date of Admission:,19.12.1969, "Parijaat" 26/1Shanker Mutt Road, Basavana Gudi,Phone:,2313861
```

But I am getting as follows

```
Name:,Mr.Srinivasan.N,Designation:,Proprietor,CODISSIA - Designation:,(Past President, CODISSIA),Name of the Industry:,Arian Soap Manufacturing Co,Specification:,LIFE,Date of Admission:,19.12.1969
"Parijaat" 26/1Shanker Mutt Road, Basavana Gudi,Phone:,2313861
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe what you want to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eachbox` is either class `members_box1` or `members_box2`, so iterating over `eachbox` will print every box contents on a separate line, when really you want both on one line. One way to get around this would be like this:

```
box1s = soup.find_all('div', class_='members_box1')
box2s = soup.find_all('div', class_='members_box2')
for box1, box2 in zip(box1s, box2s):
    data =  [re.sub('\s+', '', text).strip().encode('utf8') for text in box1.find_all(text=True) + box2.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
    print(','.join(data))
```